# DAP caulking inside cabinets safe?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, caulking

My apartment has some old handmade cabinets with some large seams at the edges. I started closing them with DAP latex caulking (alex Acrylic Latex Caulk Plus). I noticed that once dry if I swipe on the caulk with my finger, it leaves a bit of residue.

Is that safe for the plates and other dinnerware sitting in the cabinet?

Comment: Are you rubbing them on the caulking? Consider a coat of paint...

Comment: Yes it would leave some residue on my hand from the caulking material. I added a coat of paint a couple days ago, it doesn't do that anymore.

Comment: According to a poison site, eating it might give an upset stomach.  Might be a choking hazard if young child eats a large enough piece.

Comment: https://www.buildsite.com/pdf/dap/DAP-Alex-Plus-Acrylic-Latex-Caulk-Plus-Silicone-SDS-1769929.pdf : "Not a hazardous substance or mixture."

Comment: "Once dry" - is that the initial "dry" time or the "full cure" time listed on the caulk tube? Many caulks are paintable and list a short period (2-4 hours, generally) where they can be painted and/or are water proof, but an additional time period (usually 24-hours) where they are fully cured.